# Debugging ANT script initiated via a Python script

Tags: python, eclipse, debugging, ant, pydev

I have a set of Python scripts that sets up various parameters/properties for ANT script based on various conditions that are checked in the Python scripts and then invokes/executes the appropriate ANT build script.
I initiate the Python script from my Eclipse IDE. I have the PyDev plug-in installed in Eclipse.
I am able to debug the python script but cannot debug the ANT scripts, maybe because it doesn't get invoked as 'Run ANT Script'.
Is there a way to debug an ANT script initiated by Python (or any other mechanism for that matter)?

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with multiple languages, the way for debugging is regular debugging in one and remote debugging in the other... I'm guessing the ant debug uses the regular java debug which supports remote debugging, so, you can probably try that (although I haven't tried it here to confirm).